# How to use Facebook pages shortcuts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, url-shortening

I have just created an user name for my page (`AcridBlogsEN`), so it is now accessibe under:

```
https://www.facebook.com/AcridBlogsEN
```

In a confirmation message Facebook told me that I can use:

```
fb.me/AcridBlogsEN
```

in addition to main URL.

However any attempt of using this shortcut fails -- I'm getting empty page in Chrome and Firefox and "This page cannot be found" in Internet Explorer. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use the full URL of the site i.e `https://fb.me/AcridBlogsEN`

Often when browsers interpret links they cut of the `https://` section this does not mean that you should ommit it, when providing someone with the link.